# Doctrine2 extra column or table for extension

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I want to make Doctrine 2 extension, that will add an extra field to entity. I will also need new table. Field and table will be based on my custom annotation added to that entity. I think it must be added somehow in `loadClassMetadata` event.

can You provide some info how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I foud it.

Event Subscriber can subscribe also to ORM tool events, such as `postGenerateSchemaTable` event.

```
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolEvents::postGenerateSchemaTable,
        Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolEvents::postGenerateSchema,
    );
}
```

in event you can get schema object, and insert modify it there

```
$schema = $eventArgs->getSchema();
$schema->createTable( ... )
```